# Rails 3 nested form submits

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Im new to rails so this may seem like a silly question but why is it that when i have more than one submit button, one button will fail to do anything and the other button will submit the entire form. I need to be able to update a form, whent this happens a legend will drop down and then id need to enter other data. When this data is entered i need to press a button that will submit only this data to be displayed just above the input field using jquery and Ajax. My problem is submitting the data in the text field wont work because it submits the whole form.

Can someone please explain this and set me off on the right track?
Also any jquery tutorials anyone knows of (especially the unobstrusive ones) woudl be great!

Comment: Can you clear up your question a little bit?  It's a tad hard to understand.  Check [this](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) out for a good UJS in Rails3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like do not suggest you to use multiple submits buttons with according to overall UX principles. if you want to do multiple submits, use jQuery inline things, like [jQuery.validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)

Comment: Sorry the late reply... what i was trying to do more than anything was nested forms and ajax.

Comment: anyway, try to keep away from nested forms for single inputs, be JS unobtrusive